# Quickest way to see if my ssl VPN server works

Tags: vpn, ssl

I recently obtained an **"array networks spx2000"**. I don't really plan on using it but before I can actually do anything with it, I need to determine if it works or not. What is the simplest way to determine that it's atleast not bricked? I can turn it on and it says it's running without error, but without actually testing for what it does, is this enough to guerentee that it works?  I'm assuming not, that's why I'm asking.

Now, it was slightly used before I got it. I'm not sure as to what extent though. I wasn't given the nine pin cable for it. I was only given the power cord and the server itself really.

**My Question**

What is the easiest way to test to see if it works at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to know whether something works is to test what it actually does.

Imagine that instead of testing a network device, you were testing a refrigerator. Just because it turns on and starts humming, doesn't actually mean that it's working properly. To test the refrigerator, you would check the temperature of the air.

If your device turns on and doesn't display any errors, there's a good chance it's working properly. But until you actually test the intended usage, you don't know that it's doing anything more than being a space heater.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start by finding a manual for your device.  It will almost certainly tell you that, and a lot more you should know about it.